# trying to implement formatted date like 9/8/1636 and January 4, 2002 output should be YY-MM-DD

Tags: python-3.x

working as I expected when I gave the input date is  9/8/1636 expected output should be 1636-09-08
the program should be accepted as input on September 8, 1636 output should be the same as above

DateTime and some others did not work. looking for some help with a question?
from datetime import datetime

def convert_date_format(user_input):

```
months = [
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
]

try:
    month, day, year = map(int, user_input.split("/"))
    if 1 <= month <= 12 and 1 <= day <= 31:
        return f"{year:04d}-{month:02d}-{day:02d}"
except ValueError:
    pass
try:
    date_parts = user_input.split()
    month = months.index(date_parts)
    day = int(date_parts.rstrip(","))
    year = int(date_parts)
    date_object = datetime.strptime(month, day, year)
    if 1 <= month <= 12 and 1 <= day <= 31:
        formatted_date = date_object.srtftime("%y-%m-%d")
    return formatted_date
except ValueError:
    pass
```

def main():
while True:
user_input = input("Date (9/8/1638) or January 8,1936: ")
result = convert_date_format(user_input)
if result:
print(f"Date:{result}")
break

main()

Comment: You need to edit your question, adding the code that you are trying, the output it is giving you and what you want it to give you. As it stands we have no idea what or where your code is wrong, because you have not provided it.